# Grails spock- how to mock/stub a particular method of class

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking, spock

I am writing Junit testcases for a Grails project.

Here I am using Spock framework to write testcases.

Here I am trying to test following method.

But I want to mock/stub the rest.post method. I don't want call the actual url passed.

```
 def RestResponse restPost(String url, Map headerMap, Map jsonDataMap) {
    RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
    RestResponse response = rest.post(url) {
        headerMap.each { k, v -> header(k, v) }
        header('contentType', 'application/json')
        header('Accept-API-Version', 'resource=2.0,protocol=1.0')
        if (jsonDataMap)
            json(jsonDataMap)
    }
    response
}
```

I tried with MockFor. It is calling actual url.

```
   void "test restPost"() {
    setup:
    RestResponse resMock = new RestResponse()
    def httpBuildMock = new MockFor(RestBuilder)
    httpBuildMock.demand.post(_) >>  resMock

    when:
    def url = "http://testme"
    def headerMap = [
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'encodedStr'
    ]
    def dataMap = [
            'operation': 'replace',
            'field'    : 'userPassword',
            'value'    : 'devicePassword'
    ]
    RestResponse res = service.restPost(url, headerMap, dataMap)

    then:
    res
}
```

So how to mock/stub a particular method of class?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a seperate method to create the RestBuilder so createRestBuilder and then return a mock everytime this method is called:

```
   def RestResponse restPost(String url, Map headerMap, Map jsonDataMap) {
    RestBuilder rest = createRestBuilder()
    RestResponse response = rest.post(url) {
        headerMap.each { k, v -> header(k, v) }
        header('contentType', 'application/json')
        header('Accept-API-Version', 'resource=2.0,protocol=1.0')
        if (jsonDataMap)
            json(jsonDataMap)
    }
    response
}
```

then define service with

```
def service = Spy(ServiceClass) {
  // stub a call on the same object
  createRestBuilder() >> Mock(RestBuilder)
}
```

Comment: Or, create a Factory bean injected by spring.  This avoids using Spy for your class under test.